# xslt query help required for substring

Tags: xslt

May I know how to implement the logic
Select FIRST 4 Chars & REMOVE chars after "-". My input is 4536-765 and output should be 4536.
For this I have implement the substring and it worked fine.
But if the input is 45-3632 the output should be 4536.
How should I write a query which will cater both the requirement in XSLT version 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
substring(translate(input, '-', ''), 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specification isn't very clear (you say you want to remove characters after "-", but your second example retains some characters after the hyphen.)

From these examples it looks like `substring(translate(X, '-', ''), 1, 4)`